# Transfering a file with cat changes it

Tags: transfer, ascii

I am trying to transfer some video from a embedded linux + camera to my computer through an USB cable. What I am doing is `cat file > /dev/ttyGS0` on the card side and `cat /dev/ttyACM0 > file` on the computer file. The file is different after the transfer.
I tried to generate the same file on both sides (numbers from 1 to 10000, 1 by line) and transfer the one on the card to my PC. Here is what `od -x` gives me:

```
head transferedFile -n 10 | od -x
0000000 0d31 320a 0a0d 0d33 340a 0a0d 0d35 360a
0000020 0a0d 0d37 380a 0a0d 0d39 310a 0d30 000a
0000037

head originalFile -n 10 | od -x
0000000 0a31 0a32 0a33 0a34 0a35 0a36 0a37 0a38
0000020 0a39 3031 000a
0000025
```

The hexadecimal code is different. It looks like the transfer adds `0d` symbols (CR, carriage return) to the file.

Do you know why? Do you know how to get the exact file after transfer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
cat
```

is made for copying textfiles

```
dd
```

is used for a bit-for-bit copy